# How to get cookie from another localhost to another domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I'm not found solution in JavaScript to get a cookie in localhost domain to domain.com (for exemple)

I use `react-cookies` I make `cookie.load('user_auth_stg')`

`user_auth_stg` : stored by domain.com (not stored by localhost domain)

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.

You can manipulate the cookeis (unless they are `httpOnly`) for the domain of the HTML document the JS is running in with `document.cookie`.

You cannot read or write cookies for any other kind of request in the page.

If you want to set a cookie for `example.com` (and not load an HTML document from `example.com`) then you must make an HTTP request to `example.com` and have it respond with a `Set-Cookie` header.